# Oil in water coolant

Tags: engine, oil, coolant, kia, water

I have a 2005 KIA Sorento Limited Edition suv which I recently bought secondhand...i just found out that black oil is present in the water coolant, is it safe to still drive it? What could possibly be the problem is and how to solve the problem? Im quite a newbie car owner.

Answer (score 1):

The oil can contaminate you coolant system hoses causing premature failure. The cause could range from a bad engine oil cooler to a cracked oil galley leaking into the coolant system to someone who accidentally put oil in the coolant. But it definitely needs to be looked at by a pro.